# Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-cmdlet

I am learning SharePoint and more specifically provisioning with PowerShell. I can't use cmdlets as Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate or Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate, when execute them PS return that are not cmdlets. I don't know if I need to install something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Felipe,

These cmdlets are existed in legacy PnP but replaced by a new cmdlet in the current PnP.

- [Upgrading from the Legacy version of PnP PowerShell | PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/upgrading.html)
- [PnP PowerShell | PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/)

And the new corresponding cmdlet is:

- [Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate.html)

More reference:

- https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/285

BR

Comment: Thank you so much. With the new cmdlets all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the PnP.Powershell Documentation (https://github.com/pnp/powershell) that links you to the installation guide (https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html)

Basically you need to run `Install-Module -Name "PnP.PowerShell"` from a powershell console

Comment: I have already installed the PnP.PowerShell module. If I list all the cmdlets (get-command -CommandType Cmdlet) cannot find either Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate or Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate

Comment: When installing, are you using PowerShell in Admin mode?